# Making a density plot for an expression

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have defined a function the energy $E$ of a given system by

```
f1[A_,α_,γ_,κ_,V0_,σ_,Rc_,k_]:=(π*A^2)/(2*k)+(π*γ*σ^2)/α (A^2+PolyLog[2,-A^2α]/α)+((π^2)*(σ^4)*κ*(A^4)*V0 )/2+(Sqrt[2π]*π^2*σ^5*κ*A^4*V0)/(4Rc) Exp[σ^2/(2Rc)](-1+Erf[σ/(Sqrt[2]*Rc)])
```

After fixing the values of $A,\alpha,V0,Rc$ and $k$, I want to find the values of $\sigma$ that makes $E$ minimum while varying $\gamma$ and $\kappa$. Finally, I would like to make a density plot of the results obtained.

The question is, how can this be done?

In my attempts to solve the problem, I fixed some values for the variables aforementioned. Next, I created a Table under the name **mf**, which stores the $f[\gamma,\kappa,\sigma]$ for $\gamma$ and $\kappa$ varying from $(-100,0)$ and $(0,100)$, respectively.

```
mf=Table[f1[1,1,γ,κ,0.003,σ,10^-6,1],{γ,-100,0,1},{κ,0,100,1}]
```

In what follows, I was thinking of minimizing each of the elements of **mf** with respect to $\sigma$ and finally, make the plot. I even tried to implement it but it didn't work out. I am probably making mistakes.

Comment: You can see what's happening with `E` by using `DensityPlot3D[f1[1,1,γ,κ,0.003,σ,10^-6,1], {\[Gamma], -100, 0}, {\[Kappa], 0, 100}, {\[Sigma], 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> Automatic]`.

Comment: To find minimum you can define appropriate function `f[\[Gamma]_?NumericQ, \[Kappa]_?NumericQ] := Module[{m =  NMinimize[f1[1, 1, \[Gamma], \[Kappa], 0.003, \[Sigma], 10^-6, 1], \[Sigma]]}, {\[Gamma], \[Kappa], \[Sigma] /. Last[m], 
   First@m}]`. Then make a table `Quiet@Table[f[\[Gamma], \[Kappa]], {\[Gamma], -100, 0, 10}, {\[Kappa], 0, 100, 10}];` and `ListDensityPlot3D[Select[Flatten[%, 1], #[[-1]] > -5000 &], PlotLegends -> Automatic]`.